# Use onkey() to do multiple functions with Python turtle

Tags: python, keyboard, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to write a basic turtle drawing game/program and I've been using `onkey(function, "key")` to have the user input keystrokes. Well I wanted the user to be able to change the width of the pen by either hitting the up key to increase the width by one, or the down key to decrease the width by one. I know I need some kind of loop, but I don't really know where to implement it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I would suggest adding the code that you already have and show us where your error/road-block is. Questions that are answered in the: Here is my Code, Here is my Problem, Here is what I've Tried - are much more accepted. Try and edit your post to help us, help you

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example that will make the turtle walk in a continuous circle while you press up and down arrows to change the pen width:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def larger():
    size = turtle.pensize()

    if size < 10:
        turtle.pensize(size + 1)

def smaller():
    size = turtle.pensize()

    if size > 1:
        turtle.pensize(size - 1)

def move():
    turtle.circle(150, extent=3)
    screen.ontimer(move, 100)

turtle = Turtle()

screen = Screen()
screen.onkey(larger, "Up")
screen.onkey(smaller, "Down")
screen.listen()

move()

screen.mainloop()
```

Make sure you click on the window first to make it the key listener.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can't, but you can call the function insde the function you bind to the key:

```
from turtle import *

def function1():
    do_that = "do that"
    print(do_that)

def function2():
    do_this = "do this"
    print(do_this)
    function1()

onkey(function2, "space")
```

---

do this

do that

---

It worked for me ;)

Comment: The OP's question was about how to change the pen width using the Up or Down arrow keys.  This answer ignores that and answers something that wasn't asked.